# Pivot Rows to Column By Group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am looking for a code which can transpose row to column using the group by in the SQL Server 2008.

This is my table :

```
Name   |  Stdy   |  Val
-------+---------+-------
Kunjan | Technic |  80
Kunjan | Sains   |  90
Kunjan | Sport   |  60
Shone  | Technic |  60
Shone  | Sains   |  80
Shone  | Sport   |  70
Peudd  | Technic |  85
Peudd  | Sains   |  75
Peudd  | Sport   |  90
```

What I want to eventually display is something like this (for the data above):

```
Stdy    | Kunjan | Shone | Peudd
--------+--------+-------+-------
Technic |  80    |  60   |  85
Sains   |  90    |  80   |  75
Sport   |  60    |  70   |  90
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done using `PIVOT` operator

```
select  *
from    yourtable
        pivot 
        (
            max(Val)
            for Name in ([Kunjan], [Shone], [Peudd])
        ) p
```

or conditional `CASE` statement. There are lots of example, just do a search on it

EDIT : for dynamic case

```
declare @sql    nvarchar(max),
        @col    nvarchar(max)

select  @col    = isnull(@col + ',', '') + Name
from    yourtable
group by Name

print   @col 

select  @sql    = 
'
select  *
from    youtable
        pivot 
        (
            max(Val)
            for Name in (' + @col + ')
        ) p
'

print   @sql
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: but then how do I make the name flexible, because the Count of names or the name is not always the same

Comment: then you will required `Dynamic SQL`. Give me few mins, I will update my answer